# Augmented reality using artoolkit

Tags: augmented-reality, artoolkit

I have an scenario where i want to render product image on markers. But all the details of that particular product (like its .obj , .mtl file) will come from webservice. So is it possible to render image of product at runtime using artoolkit ? Is dynamic image rendering is possible using artoolkit native ?

Answer (score 1):

In short, it depends of your tool, not of ARToolKit. ARToolKit provides pose information for markers, what you do with them depends of the tool you're using.

I assume you are using Unity, then you can have a plane with a texture and make the texture dynamic based on the downloaded file.

I haven't done that in Unity, but I'll be very surprised if it wasn't possible.